Multipage PDF to single image with multi page conversion
I am trying to convert a multipage PDF to a single image.
From my code, I can only generate a multi(list of) images.
How can we create a single image with a multi page from PD?
Below is my code:
**
import requests
from pdf2image import convert_from_path
url = 'https://education.github.com/git-cheat-sheet-education.pdf'
r = requests.get(url, stream=True)
      
with open('F:/New folder/metadata.pdf', 'wb') as f:
    f.write(r.content)
    
    
pages = convert_from_path('F:/New folder/metadata.pdf', 500,poppler_path=r'C:\poppler-0.68.0\bin')    
        
for count, page in enumerate(pages):
   page.save(f'F:/New folder/out{count}.jpg', 'JPEG')

**
Request any suggestions/modifications from above code?

You could pre-process the PDF with
cpdf -impose-xy "1 0" in.pdf -o out.pdf
Now the PDF is only one page, and you can convert it to an image.

for this you will have to use the Pillow library which makes it possible to manipulate the Images by taking the max page width and sum of the page height
so python knows what height and width should the image have and after that you can start looping inside the every page to paste the pages together but here you will have to tell python at which position the images need to be saved this you can do by telling python to loop through the pages where the first position should be at 0 for example and the other need to start at previous page height which can be xyz px this will be saved at the position to do all of that this the code you need :
from PIL import Image

#....your code....# 
image = Image.new('RGB', (max(page.width for page in pages), sum(page.height for page in pages)))

prev_postion= 0
for page in pages:
    image.paste(page, (0, prev_postion))
    prev_postion+= page.height

image.save('combinedImage.jpg')

PS: you don't need to use this line of code :
for count, page in enumerate(pages):
    page.save(f'out{count}.jpg', 'JPEG')


Yeah you can't make a multi-page JPEG or PNG. There is a file format for multi-page images: TIFF. Here's how you can create one:
from pdf2image import convert_from_path
from PIL import Image

# Convert the PDF to a list of images
images = convert_from_path('F:/New folder/metadata.pdf')

# Save the images as a multi-page TIFF
images[0].save('output.tiff', 'TIFF', save_all=True, append_images=images[1:])

